# can't save variable from a form

Tags: forms, ubercart

i'm reviewing the source code of a module, the following is the code

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_userpoints api().
 */
function uc_userpoints_discount_userpoints($op, $points = 0, $uid = 0, $event = '') {
  $userpoints_translation = userpoints_translation();
  switch($op) {
    case 'setting':
      if (module_exists('uc_cart') && module_exists('uc_payment')) {
        $group = 'uc_userpoints_discount';
        $form[$group] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#collapsible' => TRUE,
          '#collapsed' => TRUE,
          '#title' => t('Ubercart Discount Options'),
        );    
        $form[$group][USERPOINTS_UC_DISC] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('!Points used in discount (for every @currency)', array('!Points' => $userpoints_translation['!Points'], '@currency' => variable_get('uc_currency_code', 'USD'))),
          '#default_value' => variable_get(USERPOINTS_UC_DISC, 1),
          '#size' => 5,
          '#maxlength' => 5,
        );
        $form[$group][UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_MAXP] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Enter the maximum percentage of the order total that can be discounted using points. Please do not include a % sign'),
          '#default_value' => variable_get(UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_MAXP, 100),
          '#size' => 5,
          '#maxlength' => 5,
        );
        $form[$group][USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT] = array(
          '#type' => 'radios',
          '#title' => t('Enable !points as a discount method', userpoints_translation()),
          '#default_value' =>  variable_get(USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT,1),
          '#options' => array(t('No'), t('Yes')),
        );
    $form[$group][USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_CATEGORY] = array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => t('Discount Category'),
          '#description' => t('Category to assign awarded !points.', userpoints_translation()),
          '#default_value' => variable_get(USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_CATEGORY, NULL),
          '#options' => userpoints_get_categories(),
        );
        $form[$group][UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_MODERATE] = array(
          '#type' => 'radios',
          '#title' => t('Moderate userpoints transaction'),
          '#default_value' => variable_get(UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_MODERATE, 0),
          '#options' => array(t('No'), t('Yes')),
        );
        $form[$group][UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_CLASSES] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkboxes',
          '#title' => t('Product classes discounts can be applied to'),
          '#description' => t('Leave blank for all.'),
          '#default_value' => variable_get(UC_USERPOINTS_DISCOUNT_CLASSES, array()),
          '#options' => uc_product_type_names(),
        );
      }
      return $form;
    break;
  }
}
```

i try to update the value of USERPOINTS_UC_DISC, it's not work, but other field is work fine, anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: How are you trying to update USERPOINTS_UC_DISC value ?

Comment: only return the current/default value that is 1